# source BYTE "This is the source string",0 target BYTE SIZEOF source DUP(0),0

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

What is SIZEOF referring to? Is it referring to the size of the source (lengthOf * TYPE which is equal to number of elements in the array * the size of each element)? Also, can someone explain DUP(0),0? This is referring to Assembly x86 MASM. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIZEOF` simply denotes the [size of a type or structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzbax489.aspx).

It refers to whatever you put after the `SIZEOF` keyword.

```
SIZEOF element     ; refers to a single element in the array.  
SIZEOF wholearray  ; sizeof(element) * number_of_elements_in_array.
```

Because it is resolved at compile-time it will only work if the size of an array is static.

[The syntax for `DUP` is:](http://www.ousob.com/ng/asm/ng35b8c.php)

```
count DUP (initialvalue [[, initialvalue]]...)

10 DUP (0)        ; 10 zero's
2 DUP (3 DUP ("A"), "BC")  ; "AAABCAAABC"
```

First you get a repeat count, then the keyword `DUP` and then a specification of what to repeat in brackets.
The repeat spec may include additional `DUP` statements.